# In OpenCV, what does descriptorType() of DescriptorExtractor class return?

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I detected key points and extracted the features.

```
vector<vector<KeyPoint> > key_points;
SiftFeatureDetector feature_detector;
feature_detector.detect( db_images_gray, key_points);

Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> descriptor_extractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("SURF");
descriptor_extractor->compute( db_images_gray, key_points,  descriptors);

cout << "Size: " << descriptor_extractor->descriptorSize() << " Type: " << descriptor_extractor->descriptorType() << endl;
```

The above cout gives  *"Size: 64 Type: 5"*  as a result. I know the meaning of size. I wonder the meaning of that 5 stands for the type of the descriptor extractor. I search it but couldn't find anything relating to decriptorType().

PS: I am aware of using SIFT detector and SURF extractor. Using OpenCV 2.4.10.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the descriptor corresponds to the `descriptors.type()` (`CV_8U`, `CV_32F`, etc.).

The descriptor type is related with the nature of the descriptor. For example, the type of SIFT and SURF will be `CV_32F` whereas the type of ORB will be `CV_8U` as it is a binary descriptor.

It is also closely related to the type of norm to use for matching descriptors (`descriptor_extractor->defaultNorm()`): `NORM_L2` and its derived for real descriptor and `NORM_HAMMING` and its derived for binary descriptors.

Comment: I just come across this code and in which ORB detector and descriptor is used but the code is as below <br>                                                         private final Mat mReferenceCorners =
            new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
      private final Mat mCandidateSceneCorners =
            new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
        private final Mat mSceneCorners = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
        private final MatOfPoint mIntSceneCorners = new MatOfPoint();
Is this sample code correct? Please let me know